# Changing video resolution in n95 with J2ME

Tags: video, java-me, camera, nokia, n95

We've tried using the parameters in the capture url as documented:

capture://video?height=480&width=360

No combination of width and height works. We always get an error -6 when creating the player.

capture://video works fine but the videos are ridiculously small.

Is it possible to record at a higher resolution on the N95?

Answer (score 0):

-6 is the following Symbian C++ error code : KErrArgument An argument is out of range.

At Least, it makes sense.

You can probably find your answer in the Nokia JavaME developer library:
http://www.forum.nokia.com/Resources_and_Information/Documentation/Java/

something like
"Note: S60 3rd Ed. FP2: All FP2 products support QCIF (176x144) resolution. Other resolutions – e.g. CIF (352x288), QVGA (320x240) and VGA (640x480) – may be supported in some devices. "

gives you a few specific values to try.

Note that you may need to specify an encoding like "video/3gp" in you capture url.

Comment: We tried before with the supported resolutions, but not with the video/3gp encoding as well. I'll check it out.

Comment: video.encodings shows "video/3gpp2" and "video/mp4"

Well, we've tried it with the following options:

capture://video?encoding=mp4
capture://video?encoding=3gp
capture://video?encoding=3gpp
capture://video?encoding=3gpp2

As well as with the width/height as above.

All show "Not supported locator"